# Creating Custom IBDesignable UITextField

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to create a custom UITextField and set a custom bordercolor. I have created an IBInspectable property for borderColor as well and if i use the set and get methods for it, I am able to set it using Storyboard.

Now instead what i want to do is have a pre-defined border color value(which is the default value) so i am trying to call the didSet Method and do the setup there. I am not sure how to do that. The default value doesn't work and gives an error if I import in my storyboard in the line -

```
self.layer.borderColor=(UIColor.KGColorPalette.entryBoxBorderColor as! CGColor)
```

**Error in Storyboard**

> error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed

**Code:**

```
@IBDesignable class KGIBDesignableTextField: UITextField {

 @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.KGColorPalette.entryBoxBorderColor {
    didSet {
        setup()
    }
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setup()
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setup()
}
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setup()
}


func setup(){
    textColor = UIColor.KGColorPalette.textEntryFontColor
    self.layer.borderColor=(UIColor.KGColorPalette.entryBoxBorderColor as! CGColor)   
    backgroundColor=UIColor.KGColorPalette.entryBoxShadeFillColor
    font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
    textAlignment = .left


}
```

}

If it would help, I checked my xcode Crash logs as well and it gave the below error -

> Thread 0 Crashed:
>   0   com.kapsymtech.ios.KGCustomUIComponentsTarget   0x0000000116932dd8 _TFC26KGCustomUIComponentsTarget23KGIBDesignableTextField5setupfT_T_ + 152 (KGIBDesignableTextField.swift:65)
>   1   com.kapsymtech.ios.KGCustomUIComponentsTarget   0x0000000116932acb _TFC26KGCustomUIComponentsTarget23KGIBDesignableTextFieldcfT5frameVSC6CGRect_S0_ + 331 (KGIBDesignableTextField.swift:56)
>   2   com.kapsymtech.ios.KGCustomUIComponentsTarget   0x0000000116932ba7 _TToFC26KGCustomUIComponentsTarget23KGIBDesignableTextFieldcfT5frameVSC6CGRect_S0_ + 71
>   3   com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x0000000107a8fb23 -[UIView(IBCocoaTouchToolIntegration) initWithMarshalledValues:orderedKeys:ignoredKeys:globalMarshallingContext:] + 131
>   4   com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x0000000107aaf51c -[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage initWithRequest:globalMarshallingContext:] + 3100
>   5   com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x0000000107aae143 +[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage objectPackageFromRequest:] + 67
>   6   com.apple.IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation    0x0000000107ab1311 +[IBCocoaTouchToolObjectPackage decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 106
>   7   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a493aa3 -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] + 112
>   8   com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a51f724 -[IBObjectBasedMarshallingRequest initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 135
>   9   com.apple.dt.IBAutolayoutFoundation 0x000000010a3d73bb -[IBAutolayoutOperationMarshallingRequest initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 59
>   10  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a48b335 +[NSObject(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] + 65
>   11  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a493aa3 -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] + 112
>   12  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a559ffa -[IBMessageReceiveChannel deliverMessage:toTarget:withArguments:context:result:] + 393
>   13  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a559a65 **88-[IBMessageReceiveChannel runBlockingReceiveLoopNotifyingQueue:notifyingTarget:context:]_block_invoke + 120
>   14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010dbe3792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>   15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010dbcc4e0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 292
>   16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010dbe3792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>   17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010dbcb247 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1041
>   18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010bac1909 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
>   19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010ba87ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2164
>   20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010ba87016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
>   21  com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010a8f3600 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
>   22  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a525bbc -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 465
>   23  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a525d85 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 119
>   24  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010a52689e +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1186
>   25  IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch    0x0000000107a04ba7 main + 34
>   26  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000010dc2c65d start + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line to:

```
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.KGColorPalette.entryBoxBorderColor.cgColor
```

from:

```
self.layer.borderColor=(UIColor.KGColorPalette.entryBoxBorderColor as! CGColor)
```

You cant typecast `UIColor` to `CGColor`. A forced cast like that would crash the application.

Comment: Thanks this reduced the compile time error. This was a stupid mistake from my side. Though i have another problem. when i run the app i don't see it on the UI though :(

Comment: Glad to know that the crash fixed with my answer. You may have to post a question with more detail about this new issue. Probably add some screenshot too in that question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to solve the problem on my own first and then put up a new one :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting. From your code, I dont see any reason for not showing the color. Did you try hardcoding color like "red" or "blue" and then is it appearing?

Comment: Sure, try to solve yourself first, then post a question with screenshot. We can check it.

Comment: Actually its not the color. I am not even seeing the UITextField in its place.